# How-To forward pan gesture from a scrollview to another scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have two UIScrollViews and i want to let the other scrollview scroll too if the user scrolls in a scrollview. I have read a solution that involves passing the pangesturerecognizer from the originally panned scrollview to the other scrollview but if i do that the original scrollview does not scroll at all.

I found out, that there is a delegate method

```
(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

but if I try to hook up the delegate of the pangesturerecognizers of the scrollviews my app crashes.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to update the Bounds of the second ScrollView

Something like :-

```
CGRect updateTheViewWithBounds = viewToUpdate.bounds;
updateTheViewWithBounds.origin = scrolledView.contentOffset;
viewToUpdate.bounds = updateTheViewWithBounds;
```

This Will do the Job.

As Seen from comments , I will give a small Example.

Create the two scrollView onto The UiViewController

```
scrollOne = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [scrollOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [scrollOne setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 200, 300)];
    [scrollOne setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];
    scrollOne.delegate = self;

    scrollTwo = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [scrollTwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [scrollTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(230, 20, 200, 300)];
    [scrollTwo setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];
    scrollTwo.delegate = self;


    [self.view addSubview:scrollOne];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollTwo];
```

Conform to the UIScrollView Delegates and implement the same.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if([scrollView isEqual:scrollOne])
    {
        CGRect updateTheViewWithBounds = scrollOne.bounds;
        updateTheViewWithBounds.origin = scrollOne.contentOffset;
        scrollTwo.bounds = updateTheViewWithBounds;
        [scrollTwo flashScrollIndicators];
    }
    else if([scrollView isEqual:scrollTwo])
    {
        CGRect updateTheViewWithBounds = scrollTwo.bounds;
        updateTheViewWithBounds.origin = scrollTwo.contentOffset;
        scrollOne.bounds = updateTheViewWithBounds;
        [scrollOne flashScrollIndicators];
    }
}
```

Scrolling any of the above scrollView will scroll both the scrollView.

Comment: That will only work if one scrollview does not ever get scrolled, am I right? :(

Comment: Whenever the first scrollview changes , in the delegate , update the corresponding other scrollView

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the scrollView:DidScroll delegate method? Do you know how i can use this method and still be able to let the scrollviews scroll at a different speed?

Comment: @roronoazorro what if i actually want only *one* of the views to scroll.. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041851/how-to-pass-a-pangesturerecognizer-from-one-scrollview-to-another/20043309?noredirect=1#20043309) question out